# Understanding the proof of a transcendental criterion regarding palindromic continued fraction.

Tags: number-theory, continued-fractions, transcendental-numbers

I am trying to understand the proof of theorem 2.1 from the following paper: https://aif.centre-mersenne.org/item/10.5802/aif.2306.pdf.

Basically the authors prove that given $\alpha=[0;a_1,a_2,\dots,a_l,\dots]$, if the continued fraction starts with arbitrarily long palindromes, then $\alpha$ is transcendental.

The proof is very easy to follow, however I don't understand why they can assume that $0<\alpha<1$ and why $q_n\leq (a_n+1)q_{n-1}$. Clearly I am missing something very obvious, but I can't see what is it.

Comment: Obviously , $\alpha$ is between $0$ & $1$ because the continued fraction starts with $0$ : $\alpha=0+1/[a_1+\cdots]$ : Obviously , the Integer Part is $0$ !

Comment: whoops, that was very much obvious. Thank u, but now the question becomes, why are they restricting themselves to such cases?

Comment: Every $\alpha$ larger than $1$ will have the $a_0$ term. Subtracting that will give new $alpha$ between $0$ & $1$ where the continued fraction starts with $0$ ! That "Shifting" will not change the "rationality/irrationality/transcendence" of $\alpha$. Hence , there is no restriction here : all $\alpha$ Cases are covered. Using small $\alpha$ is a Stylistical Choice , which might make the Proof easier !

Comment: Not true, consider $[0,1,1,1,1,1,\cdots]$ as a counterexample.

Comment: It is not clear which is not true , @Peter , are you claiming your Counter-Example is larger than 1 , countering my earlier comment ? or are you claiming OP theorem is not true , where I too am not convinced ? Paper is not really making much sense to me !